# folium.GeoJson(some_data) - how to set marker type?

Tags: python-3.x, leaflet, geojson, folium

In the Marker class I can easily style points, but how to do this with an object like folium.GeoJson("some_data") where "some_data" contains  multiple points? I´ve found an [example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb) on polygons, but not with point data.

This is my code containing an array of points:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[54.73,12.37], tiles='Stamen Toner', zoom_start=13)
url = 'http://some-url'
my_zones = f'{url}/zones.json'
my_zones_load = json.loads(requests.get(my_zones).text)
folium.GeoJson(my_zones_load).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question adding your full code and data. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to style some points, and came across a few solutions in my search.
Using the example from here:

https://github.com/collinreinking/longitude_latitude_dot_plots_in_python_with_folium/blob/master/MapsTutorials.ipynb

and from the main Folium Help Page:

https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker

I was able to get the GeoJSON point file to present as I wanted it to.

I first loaded the GeoJSON into Geopandas, to perform some additional processing, but ended up with this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

pol_ = gpd.read_file('Path to file')
##...do stuff to file

pol_m = pol_.to_json()

pol = folium.GeoJson(pol_m,
                    control = False,
                    marker = folium.CircleMarker(radius = 3, # Radius in metres
                                           weight = 0, #outline weight
                                           fill_color = '#000000', 
                                           fill_opacity = 1),
                    tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields = ['feeder'],
                                                    aliases=['Feeder: '],
                                                    style = ("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;"),
                                                    sticky = True
                    )

                    ).add_to(m)
```

You can also use a lambda function to change how the point presents, based on field values...similar to this:

```
fillcolor: lambda x: {fillColor':'red' if x['properties']'Post_Cod_1'] == 'High' else 'green','fillOpacity':0.75}
```

Or something similar to that. I haven't tested that last code, but I have done something similar for a Polygon / Polyline elsewhere, I don't see why it wouldnt work with the point.